# Setting T2Unlimited in CloudFormation template

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I am currently creating a CloudFormation template.  When making an ec2 instance, I want to make it t2.nano and T2Unlimited.  From [Ec2::Instance doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-instance.html) I managed to find InstanceType property.  However, I cannot find T2Unlimited.

#### Question

- In cloud formation template, is it possible to make certain ec2 instance resource T2Unlimited?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `"CreditSpecification" : CreditSpecification` property of CloudFormation EC2 Resource. The value will be either: `standard` or `unlimited`

Answer (score 0):

From Lakhan's answer, I managed to come up with following property configuration,  which worked correctly:

```
  CreditSpecification:
    CPUCredits: unlimited
```

(Needed the CPUCredits field to make it work correctly.)